# format java source code natively based on CodeFormatterProfile

Tags: formatting, java

Is there an emacs tool to format java code according to a Java Code Formatter Profile (xml) spec, such as the one below?

https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

I'm aware I could use an after-save-hook in java mode to invoke an external tool, like eclipse, to achieve this, but I'd like to know if there is a native emacs tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-java by setting  `lsp-java-format-settings-url` to https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

```
(setq lsp-java-format-settings-url "https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml")
```

Edit: the correct url must be raw https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

Comment: The URL should be in raw right? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml.

Comment: Yes. I will update the original comment.